# Wordpress Rewrite custom URL file name with param

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm facing some troubles with htaccess rewites with Wordpress
I want this URL:

```
https://example.com/results.php?id=xxx
```

To fetch this URL:

```
https://example.com/index.php?op=results&id=xxx
```

basicaly the problem is catching the first URL
i tryed this snippet

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'results.php?$', 'index.php?results=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

It works, but an unwanted slash is added like so:

```
https://clients.lab/esallamlab/results.php/?id=123
```

*Note the (/) after (results.php)*

Any help please!

Answer (score 2):

I do not think it has anything to do with '.htaccess' file. This is how I solved this for my website

1- Go to the admin panel --> go to settings --> permalinks
2- In the 'Custom structure' section, delete the last slash`/` at the end.
3- Save changes and you should be able to see the right `url`

https://example.com/results.php?id=123